# How do I import and export a json file from a contextMenu in a chrome or firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have two manifests:

firefox:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Easy Applier",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus", "menus"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["scripts/background.js"]
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "assets/icon-16.png",
      "48": "assets/icon-48.png",
      "128": "assets/icon-128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icon-16.png",
    "48": "assets/icon-48.png",
    "128": "assets/icon-128.png"
  }
}
```

chrome:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Easy Applier",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "scripts/background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "assets/icon-16.png",
      "48": "assets/icon-48.png",
      "128": "assets/icon-128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icon-16.png",
    "48": "assets/icon-48.png",
    "128": "assets/icon-128.png"
  }
}
```

Here is my `background.js` file:

```
// import { NS, importJsonData, exportJsonData } from "./utils/index.js";
// Create context menu items
const createContextMenuItem = (menuItem) => {
  if (typeof browser !== "undefined") {
    browser.menus.create(menuItem);
  } else {
    chrome.contextMenus.create(menuItem);
  }
};

// Parent menu item
createContextMenuItem({
  id: "parentMenuItem",
  title: "Easy Applier",
  contexts: ["page"],
  // icons: {
  //   16: "assets/icon-16.png",
  //   48: "assets/icon-48.png",
  // },
});

// Child menu items
createContextMenuItem({
  id: "childMenuItem1",
  title: "Import",
  parentId: "parentMenuItem",
  contexts: ["page"],
});

createContextMenuItem({
  id: "childMenuItem2",
  title: "Export",
  parentId: "parentMenuItem",
  contexts: ["page"],
});

// Handle context menu item click
const handleMenuClick = (info, tab) => {
  switch (info.menuItemId) {
    case "childMenuItem1":
      // Perform the desired action for Child Menu Item 1
      console.log("Import clicked");
      handleImport();
      break;
    case "childMenuItem2":
      // Perform the desired action for Child Menu Item 2
      console.log("Export clicked");
      handleExport();
      break;
  }
};

if (typeof browser !== "undefined") {
  browser.menus.onClicked.addListener(handleMenuClick);
} else {
  chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(handleMenuClick);
}

function handleExport() {
  console.log("Handle export");
  // exportJsonData(NS + "-profile.json");
}

function handleImport() {
  console.log("Handle import");
  // importJsonData();
}
```

It gets called for both import and export so that is fine, but the problem I have is I need to download a JSON file from `localStorage` (or `chrome.storage.local`) for exporting...

...and for importing I need to trigger the file upload dialog and handle its contents (putting it in `localStorage` or `chrome.storage.local`).

How can I do this? `background.js` doesn't have access to the DOM. I tried doing it in the `popup.html` file but it disappears as soon as you open the file dialog so there must be a way to use events to an `invisible.html` that the `background.js` file can send messages to.

Comment: Are you looking for [messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage)?

Comment: Possibly, where would I put the message handler? Would that go in `popup.js` even if its closed?

Comment: Can you give a working example?

Comment: I think so. I don't use popups in my extensions but I do have something like `browser.runtime.sendMessage({ trigger: 'doSomething', data })` in a content script, and then a corresponding `browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (data) { ... }` in my background script, so I imagine it should work ok for a popup (as they're just another form of content script).

Comment: Does this work for both firefox and chrome?

Comment: can you expand on this? `browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (data) { ... }` I don't know what to put there.

Comment: I think I need to go the other direction background -> content script not content -> background

Comment: I got it working with script injection but localStorage key is not defined.

Comment: "`background.js` doesn't have access to the DOM" access to what DOM?

Comment: i need to push a file